# Force and motor calculation on a moving chain sprocket system

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, chain

I have a chain sprocket motor system used to move a load up. Usually I think the load would be the charge use for calculation and the torque should correspond to the load times de radius of the sprocket right?

However if the sprocket/motor also moves up a second rack, how does the load is modified? It is like the load moves twice as fast since the load moves AND the motor/sprocket/chain system as well?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you draw a diagram?

Answer (score 1):

If the sprocket is geared to a vertical track and rolls up on it while turning then the distance from the center of rotation as relates to torque is the diameter of the sprocket, not its radius. therefore Torque is doubled. And the speed of lifting is doubled too for the same rotation speed.

If the sprocket is geared to an inclined track with angle $\theta$ then its torque is

$$T= F(R+Rsin\theta)$$

- T torque
- F  force or load
- R   radius of the sprocket